# Opening all .smi files from subdirectories into one file

Tags: bash

I have a folder with number of subdirectories; each subdirectory has multiple files with `.smi` extension. I am trying to open content of all of them into one file.

I have tried this:

```
find ./*/*.smi | xargs xdg-open > one_file
find . | xargs xdg-open > one_file
xdg-open */*.smi > one_file
open **/*.smi > one_file
```

It seems that I am doing something wrong, can somebody help me?

Comment: content of your .smi files are subtitles, so just text ?

Comment: yes yes, just text :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your commands, e.g. `[...] xdg-open > one_file` will open the files one by one and send the *output* of `xdg-open` to `one_file`.

But I think you first want to merge the files, and then open the merged file.
You can use `cat` to con**cat**enate text files:

```
find . -name "*.smi" -exec cat {} + > one_file.smi
xdg-open one_file.smi
```

Comment: If my answer worked for you, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Oh, I thought I did yesterday. Thank you for reminding me and thank you once again!